# How to get User Data from the App?

Tags: ios, data-transfer

Is there a way to get data from the user while they use my app on their device (iPhone/iPad). For example, if the app fills a dictionary during the runtime about which avatar is used most of the time and which avatar not, is there a way to transfer that dictionary to me? Do I need a server?

This is my first time thinking about data transfers over the internet. I don't have any idea or any experience on how to do that. Somehow I feel it is impossible for some security reasons. I found the `NSURLConnection` class, but this seems to be only one way to move data from a server to the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand the question, but I am assuming you would like to get information about how the user is using your application?

This is definitely possible; and yes, you will need a server to send, retrieve or store the information that you require, or else there is no way to get the data from the application to you! You will need to learn how server side and client side web scripting works (if you do not know already) as this is how the application will communicate with your server.

Depending on the kind of information you are trying to retrieve, there may be security issues and Apple may not accept your application. However, if your data is specific to your application features, there should be no issue of this kind.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know which area I have to add knowledge !